# C char* + char* concatenation

Tags: c, char, strcat

I have `char* str1` and `char* str2`

I wanna concatenate like this `res = str1 + str2`

`strcat(str1, str2)` change value of str1, it is not what i need

How to get this result?

Comment: Then first copy `str1` to `res`, then `strcat(res, str2)`

Comment: ...and always make sure there's enough room for the concatenated string.

Comment: str1 changed too in my case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to first copy the first string, and then concatenate the second to that:

```
strcpy(res, str1);
strcat(res, str2);
```

... making sure `res` has enough space allocated for the result, including the null terminator.

Or as a one-liner, if you wish (thanks, Eugene Sh.):

```
strcat(strcpy(res,str1), str2)
```

Another (and safer) option is to use [`snprintf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), which assures you will not overflow the destination buffer:

```
int count = snprintf(res, sizeof res, "%s%s", str1, str2);
```

If `count` is less than the size of `res` minus one, the result was truncated to fit. Note that `res` must be an array (not decayed to a pointer) for `sizeof res` to work. If you have another source of the buffer length, you could use that instead.

(snprintf info adapted from user3386109's comment -- thank you!)

Comment: One can even chain these functions `strcat(strcpy(res,str1), str2)`

Comment: better use sprintf

Comment: @Jean-François: I don't see how?

Comment: @EugeneSh. how does `strcpy` ensure there's enough space for the concatenated string?  That looks very unsafe to me.

Comment: @MarkRansom `strcpy` doesn't, the programmer does (or not..). Sure, it's another way to shoot one's own leg, C provides many of these.